# OrderBy(): I need to page records, but I don't care about the order: How to specify a default KeySelector?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I need to page records but I don't know the Entity's fields.  Any way to OrderBy the Key (whatever it is) or simply specify some default OrderBy Lambda?

For example, I can do this with the Where Clause without knowing the Entity's properties:

```
 var myRecords = DC.Products.Where( p => p);
```

This is a case where the Skip and Take require an OrderBy, but I don't know the Entity's Key fields.

EDIT:

When I don't have OrderBy() when using Skip().Take(), I get this error:

```
The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities.
The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

Comment: I don't think your code `.Where(p => p)` can be compiled.

Comment: I assumed DC.Products is a strongly typed table in a dataset?  If your DBMS follows the same convention as a lot of other ones, then a default result set will be implicitly sorted by the clustered index of the primary key...I am assuming each of your entities will always have a primary key in the database?

Is DC.Products being sorted on any other value at any other time?

Comment: @wllmsaccnt That would be an answer :)  I thought .Skip().Take() required an OrderBy() preceding it.

Comment: @Danny Chen: I am not sure if it can be compiled, but it does return all records.

Comment: `Skip` and `Take` do *not* require an OrderBy to precede it.  `DC.Products` will return results in *some* order, you can be sure of that.  Also, as Danny mentions, the *only* way `DC.Products.Where(p => p)` would compile is if `DC.Products` is a collection of `bool` -- either that or you've defined your own overload of `.Where` that accepts a lambda that isn't a predicate (`p` is not a boolean expression).

Comment: @Kirk Wolf: I am getting a "The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'." run time error.

Comment: @Kirk Wolf: Oddly, Products is a regular table of product attributes, some nvarchar, some int, etc., and .Where(p => p) still grabs them all.  Not arguing, just observing.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the Key property name, you would have to leverage the *MetadataWorkspace* object. Once you get the name from it, you can build a dynamic query with *EntitySQL* to get the results or using the *Query Builder* methods to build an *EntitySQL* for you, like I showed below, they are just like LINQ to Entities methods except that they accept string instead of Lambdas:

```
var keyName = context
    .MetadataWorkspace
    .GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)
    .BaseEntitySets.First(meta => meta.ElementType.Name == "Product")
    .ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    var query = context.Products.OrderBy("it." + keyName);
    var anotherQuery = context.Products.Where("it." + keyName + " = 1" );
```

Comment: That is very promising and impressive. My difficulty is one cannot use the string syntax after a previous lambda expression.  The .Where(p => p...) removes the ability to extend with the OrderBy using strings.  I would need to use .Where("it. something").OrderBy("it." + keyName);  It's no so difficult except that my interface only includes lambda expressions, so I would need to somehow convert the lambda expression to string.

Comment: You can always add LINQ methods to an ObjectQuery or to query builder methods, but the only query builder method that you can add to a LINQ expression is Include. For example this is possible: .Where("it...").Where(p => p...) but not the other way around. In your case, when you want to build dynamic queries, I would write the whole query in EntitySQL as it's a perfect situation for leveraging ESQL.